# How to define dtype on read_json?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read in the following JSON to a DataFrame:

`[{"col1": 900000000000000000000}]`

When I run `pd.read_json('sample.json')` I receive error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 366, in read_json
    return json_reader.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 467, in read
    obj = self._get_object_parser(self.data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 484, in _get_object_parser
    obj = FrameParser(json, **kwargs).parse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 576, in parse
    self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", line 793, in _parse_no_numpy
    loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
ValueError: Value is too big
```

I've tried a few different ways to define the dtype on read, such as:

- `df = pd.read_json('sample.json', dtype={'col1': np.dtype('object')})`
- `df = pd.read_json('sample.json', dtype={'col1': np.object})`
- `df = pd.read_json('sample.json', dtype={'col1': str})`

Interestingly, if I change my input to the following, it works just fine with the dtype set to float64: `[{"col1": "900000000000000000000"}]`; but that's not what my input will be, unfortunately.

Any idea on why I'm not able to properly define the dtype on read? Thanks.

Comment: Are there only one such column that has this problem?

Comment: Yup. Initially this was part of a larger object, and I've isolated it to this one column. If I reduce the value of that column then I have no issues. If I remove this column from my larger object, it also works without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `json.loads` and load in all the data that isn't problematic (in this case, everything besides `col1`).

```
import json

json_data = '''[{"col1": 900000000000000000000, "col2": "abc"}, {....}]'''
data = json.loads(json_data)

c = list(set(data[0].keys()) - {'col1'})
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=c)
```

Now, we'll have to manually extract `col1`'s data, convert it to a `dtype=object` `Series`, and then add it.

```
df.insert(0, 'col1', pd.Series([d['col1'] for d in data], dtype=object))
```

```
df
                    col1 col2
0  900000000000000000000  abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was hoping to avoid a circuitous implementation as it seems odd the dtype didn't work out the door -- but having a working implementation at all is a good step. I've also found [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-6) which state interoperability concerns with implementations that exceed the range of double-precision (IEEE754); so I may try to get a change upstream.

Comment: @cmclen You're welcome. And yes, if you can, an upstream change would be better than a makeshift workaround. Better design.